How to share data between (multiple instances) of 2 unrelated components?
I have 2 unrelated components, a search bar and a table. I have a service that shares data between them. The problem is that I have multiple instances of the search + table components depending on the search. Whenever I search, it updates all tables. Is there a way for me to bind one service between 2 components?
I know I can combine both the search and table component into 1 component, but with how my project is set up, it would make things more complicated than it already is.
Without giving out too much, this is what I have.
// Data sharing service
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSharingService {

    private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    currData = this.data.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    updateSearchRes(newData: any){
        this.data.next(newData);
    }
}

// search component
onClick(e: any){
  // get search data
  this.searchResults = this.getSearchResults(e);

  // send data to service
  this.searchResults.forEach(element => {
     this.dataSharingService.updateSearchRes(element);
  });
}

// table component
ngOnInit(){
  ...

  // listen for data
  this.dataSharingService.currData.subscribe(newSearchRes => {
    this.addDataToTable(data);
  });

  ...
}


Have a look into https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store probably other way of doing stuff, or as simple as you made service. Make that service configured in root module so same instance will be shared

You need to use a simple if condition to scope the emits to a single component structure.
The HTML for the component will look like.
...
<app-search searchKey="home"/>
...
<app-table searchKey="home"/>
...

First we convert the service emit method, to emit an object with an event name, instead of just the data.
// Data sharing service
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSharingService {

    private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    currData = this.data.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    updateSearchRes(eventName: string, newData: any){
        this.data.next({eventName, data: newData });
    }
}

Now When you click on search, you take an @Input() searchKey = '', this searchKey, can be used to filter the emits received by the table.
// search component
...
@Input() searchKey = ''
...

...
onClick(e: any){
  // get search data
  this.searchResults = this.getSearchResults(e);

  // send data to service
  this.dataSharingService.updateSearchRes(this.searchKey, this.searchResults);
}

Then use this same approach, to filter on the table.
// search component
...
@Input() searchKey = '';
private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
...

...
// table component
ngOnInit(){
  ...

  // listen for data
  this.sub.add(
    this.dataSharingService.currData.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if(event.eventName === this.searchKey) {
          this.addDataToTable(event.data);  
      }
    })
  );

  ...
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}


Do you need a map for this approach since there can be multiple pairs of search+table, and there is only one BehaviorSubject?

@bestfirstsearch i thought you wanted to emit to only one table from its search pair component, both share the same key and use it to filter and narrow down the event

@bestfirstsearch For that scenario create an event name like 'emitAll', then you can change the if condition to event.eventName === 'emitAll' || event.eventName === this.searchKey, so that multiple tables catch the emit

Oh no you're right, I only want one table from a search-pair component. I'm assuming BehaviorSubject can only hold one value at a time? Unless I'm misunderstanding - I'm new to angular.

That makes sense, thank you! In this case, would I also need to do cleanup and unsubscribe from the observable?

@bestfirstsearch yes, you must, updating my answer with the same!

awesome thank you!
